# Built in function in java

Tags: java, function

What is built in function in java? I found some question and it was like "... solve this without using built in function".
So, what is it?
I know java support methods,what's different between both of them?

Comment: Methods which are part of JDK classes.

Comment: Java has a lot of functions to do common tasks. For instance, if you're supposed to sort a List "without using built-in functions", you'd want to stay away from things like `Collections.sort()`. It's usually to make sure you're learning *how* something works.

Comment: I never understood those kind of questions. I mean when was the last time when you couldn't use the JDK?

Comment: Sounds like a professor wanted his question solved without using "built-in functions"

Comment: "Built in" is not a precise term. I'd ask the author of the question what they mean exactly.

Comment: I'm guessing it means "don't use a built-in function that's specifically designed for whatever you're supposed to solve", probably like what Geobits was thinking.  So if you're given a `List` and you're supposed to sort it, you can't use the built-in sort methods, but you'd still be able to use `List` methods like `get` and `size`.  I doubt that it would mean "don't use any Java library function at all".

Answer (score 3):

It means solve it  using only methods that YOU have implemented. Do not use anything that came as a part of the JDK you installed.

JDK = Java Development Kit

It includes a rich library to assist with some of the more common tasks in java coding. It sounds like you are supposed to avoid using this library.

Comment: You may need to define JDK for the opening poster.

Comment: Would that mean that you can't use `String.equals` or `String.charAt`, for instance?

Comment: I would assume that you should not use String.equals or charAt. Those are easily implementable examples and it sounds like this is homework.

Comment: @ajb It largely depends on the person that created the original exercise. When I was in college, where questions like this were common for me (and others of course), they often allowed a very small subset such as `String.equals`, because the exercise was "how is `LinkedList` implemented", not "how is `String` implemented". Strictly speaking, though, I would say you couldn't use those methods.

Comment: @75inchpianist How is `String.charAt` "easily implementable", without using other JDK library methods?  (The source in String.java accesses a private field.)

Comment: @ajb You can use `String.toCharArray` and directly work with a copy of the `char` array that underlies the `String` for things like `String.equals` or `String.charAt`. Of course, that uses another "built-in" method, and at this stage it's getting silly trying to not use the `String` methods, and you'll probably want to reimplement a simple version of `String` yourself *if that's the exercise*.

Comment: @ajp15243 If you're saying `String.toCharArray` is acceptable and `String.charAt` is not, then this begs Mohammad's earlier question: how do you define "JDK"?  And how is anyone supposed to know what they can or can't use if an exercise says "without using built in function", when the dividing line exists only in someone's imagination?  I think the only real answer is the one given earlier: whoever wrote the exercise blew it by not providing enough information, and they need to be asked what is meant.

Comment: @ajb I thought I made it clear that one ends up just using other "built-in" methods in order to try to partially reimplement things provided in the JDK, and that the only true solution is to completely reimplement the class(es) in question.

Answer (score 3):

**Built in functions** in java are methods that are present in different API of JDK. For example `cos(double a), exp(double a)` etc are built in function of java present in `java.lang.Math` class.

**Solve without using built in functions** means if you have to calculate X raised to the power of Y, you define your own logic to calculate the result. You don't use built in function `Math.pow(X, Y)`, that returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

A built-in function is a method that is already implemented by the package you import. For example, if in your code you say,

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

And later use `Collections.sort(...)`, you are using a built-in function, since *you did not write it* - the Java developers did.

If your requirements specify you must use a non-built-in function, you must write this `sort()` (e.g.) algorithm yourself.

**TL;DR** - Built-in functions are already made. A non-built-in function is one you write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that "built in function" within a language would rather mean intrinsic function. This is not the case of any function or class that are part of the JDK. These functions and classes are not part of the Java language per se. However, most probably,  you have indeed been asked to avoid using any method or class belonging to the JDK although the expression is being used abusively.

Answer (score 0):

It's a method that is part of the Java class. Like String for example. These methods usually save time and effort as they are designed for optimal performance and have been well tested. [This article](https://www.gcreddy.com/2021/07/built-in-methods-in-java.html) helps explain with examples provided.